# Switch using array not running?

Tags: arrays, swift, switch-statement

For some reason my program refuses to run no matter what I do. Right now the code below gives me error

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_BAD_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

the code:

```
var array = [String]()
array[0] = "lmao"
switch array[0] {

case "lmao":
    print("fug")

default:
    print("fugger")

}
```

Comment: That wouldn't even run without the switch-statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allocating any space in the array - it is empty, so accessing element 0 causes an error. Use `array.append("lmao")` rather than `array[0] = "lmao"`.

Alternatively, if you know exactly how many elements you need (say, 10) use

```
var array = [String](repeating: "", count: 10)
```

as your declaration, then you can directly set `array[0]` through to `array[9]`. You'll still get an error accessing `array[10]`, because the array does not have 11 members...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `append` method to add a value into your `array`:

```
array.append("lmao")
```

It would be a good idea to take some minutes to read [Apple's documentation on swift array](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html). It will help you to understand how things like memory allocations and mutability works.

Here is a fully working example:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
var array = [String]()
array.append("lmao")
switch array[0] {

case "lmao":
    print("fug")

default:
    print("fugger")

}
```

(Which displays `fug`)